# Are there CSS class naming standards for web applications?

Tags: javascript, css, web-applications, naming-conventions

There is quite a bit of information on the intertubes going over some fundamental css naming conventions. However, most of these conventions are from  designer's point of view.

I'm going after conventions from a web application developer's point of view. As a web application grows, and UJS (unobtrusive javascript) is used throughout the codebase, what naming standards have grown around your css classes. The reason this is a little awkward is that css classes are somewhat overloaded in their use.

- On one hand, css classes are used by
  stylesheets to help present your
  content well.
- On the other hand, css
  classes are used by UJS libraries
  (like jQuery) to help tie javascript
  code to certain elements on a given
  page.

A covention that comes to mind from a rails application perspective is something like

```
.controller-action 
  { /*styles */ }
```

Other thoughts are prefixing your classes with hungarian-notion:

```
.js-controller-action
  { /* styles */ }
```

the js, prefix, would delineate those elements with ujs code attached to them.

Personally, I'm interested in this from a rails application perspective, however, I can see how this could apply to any web application framework and UJS javascript library.

Comment: The motivation for this question is the software development principle that your code should be as self documenting as possible. Does this apply to css classes in your markup in relation to UJS code?

Comment: I would consider the "UJS" Hungarian notation itself obtrusive.

Answer (score 6):

I found a good article on this.

[Structural Naming Convention in CSS](http://sixrevisions.com/css/css-tips/css-tip-2-structural-naming-convention-in-css/)

and also

[CSS coding: semantic approach in naming convention](http://woork.blogspot.com/2008/11/css-coding-semantic-approach-in-naming.html)